# Convert jquery toggle into pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like some help converting this jQuery code into "vanilla" JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-icon").click(function(){
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass('show-sidebar');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const icon = document.getElementById('menu-icon');
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sidebar.classList.toggle('show-sidebar');
    })
});
```

Comment: i need to hide scroll of body when click on side navbar menu button and navbar will scroll . and after closing navbar body can scroll . how to do it?

Comment: function mySideBarClose() {
document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}


function mySideBarOpen() {
document.body.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
}